# Select distinct emails from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have like 10 different tables all with different names, but they all contain an email_address column. I want to do a DISTINCT on all of the rows.

Pretty much my end goal is to get a number of distinct email addresses in a bunch of lists.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT email_address FROM table1
  UNION
SELECT email_address FROM table2
  UNION 
-- And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select email_address from table1
union
select email_address from table2
union
...
etc
```

`UNION` already removes duplicates. `UNION ALL` will include duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select email_address from c1

   UNION

   select email_address from c2
```

the UNION statement will remove all duplicate values.